# Why can't I run QGIS android on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-android

I wanted to be able to run QGIS on my Galaxy Tab S2.  Play store says that the device is not compatible.  But the support page lists the Tab S (first one) as supported, but doesn't mention the Tab S2.

What is it about my device that prevents the download via play store, and is there a workaround?

This was one of the reasons I bought the device, but I was mistaken in the support wiki between a Samsung Galaxy S2 (a phone) and a Tab S2?

Comment: Did you already solve the problem?
I was also thinking about buying the tab s2 for applying mobile qgis...

Comment: unfortunately no, this is the only place I've asked and I didn't receive a reply.
Is mobile QGIS different to android QGIS?

Comment: http://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/alldownloads.html?highlight=android#android says it's not working android 5 (and possibly up). I got two tablets, one with android 4.3, google says YES and one with 5.0 and google says NO

Answer (score 1):

Though this is for another version of Android, you may want to check out these installation instructions. There are a few extra steps than the typical clicking on an icon in the Play Store ([Source - QGIS Blog](https://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2014/02/21/qgis-tips-or-should-that-be-qtips-qgis-on-an-android-tablet/)):

> Enable “Allow installation of apps from unknown sources” –
>   Settings|Security.
>
> Download the installer .apk (this download should  be fixed and
>   up-to-date) and open it (on most Androids it will download to a
>   “Downloads” directory, but may be elsewhere; you can just click to
>   open the file from your file browser and it should start the
>   installer).
>
> Run the installer and select ‘download and install’. 83 MB of data
>   will get downloaded. Luckily, it is a resumable download – if it
>   fails, you can start the process off again where you left off.
>
> Confirm that you want to install (standard Android dialogue) – takes
>   about 2 minutes to finish this stage.
>
> Run QGIS: “Unpacking post-install data” … 10 seconds.
>
> QGIS requires a supporting service, available from the Play store
>   “This application requires Ministro service. Would you like to install
>   it?” Confirm and install Ministro II, only 523KB.
>
> Looks like it needs MORE libraries to run! “Qgis needs extra libraries
>   to run. Do you want to download them now?” Confirm and install the
>   QtCore libraries – a lot bigger at 31MB.

In addition, [here is a list of tested Android devices](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/android-qgis/Tested_Devices) from the QGIS help site.